# Create a read write field inside Odoo widget

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, qweb

I followed the documentation at https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/howtos/web.html

But when I tried to make a read write field I got error `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`

```
<t t-if="! widget.get('effective_readonly')">
    <input type="text"></input>
</t>
```

This code doesn't recognize `widget`. What `identifier` should I use inside the template? If there is no built in `identifier`, where to define the `identifier`? And how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `init` function

```
local.FieldNewWidget = instance.web.form.AbstractField.extend({
    init: function(parent, options) {
        this._super(parent, options);
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.set("value", "");
        this.widget = this;
    },

...
```

And here

```
    display_field: function() {
        var self = this;
        self.$el.empty();
        self.$el.append(QWeb.render('yourNewTemplate', {widget: self, data: data}));

...
```

Done